# Return back from webview to activity

Tags: java, android

I am setting up interac payment from app. For that I need to take user to interac website and from there if there is a success it'll come to internal server (called `success_url`) and if it's failed then it'll come to `failure_url`. Up to here everything is working.

But, after success or failure I need to go back to my last activity with that response (success or failure). How can I get back to the previous activity with response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override OnActivityResult in your previous activity and use bundle and setResult method to go back,

```
    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

        if (url.contains("success-url")) 
        {
           //call intent to navigate to activity
            setResult(RESULT_OK, bundle);
            ActivityWebview.this.finish();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let simply the things a bit by explicitly saying that at the end of the transaction, the web page will display a link on the page, for example: "OK", "Continue", etc... whose url will be equal with:

`<a href="success">Continue</a>`
`<a href="failure">Continue</a>`

depending of transaction status.

Now, what you could to, is to intercept the url when the user will click on that link.

This can be done by creating a custom `WebViewClient`, overriding `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`, intercept the the url, and depending of the url type take appropriate actions.

Example:

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.add_funds_web_view);
webView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebClient());
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

// ......... 

private class CustomWebClient extends WebViewClient {

   @Override
   public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
      if (url.equals("success")) {
            // set success result and finish
            return true;
      }else if (url.equals("failure")){
            // set failure result and finish
            return true;
      }
     return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
   }  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String)) to register a listener for js callback at Java code (in your activity).

Comment: but minimum sdk should be 17